# XML Config, How can I read a configuration file with a list/array of values rather than a single value

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft.extensions.configuration

If I have a configuration file with the following list of values in the configuration.

The configuration file is an xml file...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <Employees foor="bar">
    <Employee name="aaa" surname="bbb"/>
    <Employee name="ddd" surname="eee"/>
    <Employee name="fff" surname="ggg"/>
  </Employees>
</configuration>
```

Using `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`, I try to load the xml as follow

```cs
public class Employee
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public string Surname{get;set;}
}
...
public class Employees
{
  public List<Employee> Employees{ get; set;}

  public string Foo {get; set; }
}
```

```cs
...
var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
AddXmlFile(path: "\\MyConfig.config")
        .Build();

var employees = configurationBuilder.GetSection("Employees").Get<Employees>()
...
```

But the list returned is null, I am able to read single values if I move them up one level, but I would like to read a list of values inside my list.

It also does not work if I have a class within a class

For example

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <Outer foor="bar">
    <Inner name="aaa" surname="bbb"/>
  </Outer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Scenario 1** - keeping the `Employees` xml wrapper element

In order to load the `Employee` xml elements, the corresponding property on the wrapper class must have the same name; so change `Employees` to `Employee`.

Lets also correct that `foor` attribute in the xml from `<Employees foor="bar">`
to `<Employees foo="bar">` since the `Employees` class has a `Foo` property.

```
public class Employees
{
    public List<Employee> Employee { get; set;}

    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Below shows the result of retrieving the `employees` section.

```
var employees = configurationBuilder.GetSection("Employees").Get<Employees>();
```

[image]

If you don't like the singular `Employee` property, then you can make that one `private`, but have to take that into account on retrieval.
You then define a `public` `Employees` as a 'pass through' property.
Note that you can't have an `Employees` class and a property with that same name because of an [`CS0542`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0542?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0542)) compile error, which is to be fixed by renaming that class, to e.g. `Staff`.

```
public class Staff
{
    private List<Employee> Employee { get; set; }

    public List<Employee> Employees => Employee;

    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

var employees = configurationBuilder.GetSection("Employees")
    .Get<Staff>(o => o.BindNonPublicProperties = true);
```

---

**Scenario 2** - not using an `Employees` xml wrapper element

Declare the xml as below.

```
<configuration>
  <Employee name="aaa" surname="bbb" />
  <Employee name="ddd" surname="eee" />
  <Employee name="fff" surname="ggg" />
</configuration>
```

Retrieve the employees as a list of `Employee`.

```
var employees = configurationBuilder.GetSection("Employee").Get<List<Employee>>();
```

Answer (score -1):

This is one of the way, you can do it as shown:

```
<util:list id="myColours" value-type="java.lang.String">
        <value>red</value>
        <value>green</value>
        <value>blue</value>
        <value>yellow</value>
        <value>brown</value>
        <value>orange</value>
    </util:list>
```

Comment: Thanks, but, unless I misunderstood you, this is for Java, not c#, is that correct?

Comment: yes  it is java Array-list, but you can use the same way in your xml file with little syntax changes.